# Enlargen a division with a specific class on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to create a division in HTML that - on `hover` gets slightly bigger and that extends the existing division by a new one.

I suppose I need to use JavaScript for this, as there is a `onmouseover` function.

Can anyone guide me what kind of information to look up, or where to find appropriate code structures.

An example of what I am looking [is here](https://www.absolventa.de/unternehmen):

[image]

There is a box that displays new content, once one hovers over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example the use `transform: scale()` to scale the box.

```
.box {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;

  padding: 5px;

  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid crimson;

  // scale the box from horizontal center, and vertical top
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;

  // apply a transition
  transition: transform .5s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: transform .5s ease-out;
}

.box:hover {
  z-index: 20;

  transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

An example of that: https://jsfiddle.net/o5qwt01s/3/

Make sure to place the box inside a container to prevent the boxes from jumping around on hover.

A other solution is to update the width / height of the box to a higher value on hover. In this case we have to position the box `absolute` inside it's container. The downside is that you have to specify a `height` for it's container, as well for the box.

```
.col {
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  height :200px;

  display: inline-block;  
  vertical-align: top;

  margin: 10px;

}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;

  padding: 5px;

  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid crimson;

  transition: height .2s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: height .2s ease-out;
}

.box:hover {  
  z-index: 20;
  height: 300px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/24wrm8zo/3/

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked very well. I just have a question. Two questions remain. 

1) The enlarged section, when moving under instead of on top of the neighbouring section (view first screenshot)

Answer (score 1):

```css
.box {width:300px;height:200px;overflow:hidden;background-color:blue;}
.text{height:200px;padding:20px;margin:auto;color:white;box-sizing:border-box}
.secret-text { height:200px;margin:auto;background-color:red;}
.box:hover{height:auto}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<div class="text">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."</div>
<div class="secret-text">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."</div>
</div>
```

I dont think you need javascript for this . You hide the "awards-jobs" container in your given example with display:none or with specific height in parent div and overflow:hidden. Then on hover the parent div you set display:block or height:auto respectively .

Comment: If you've got multiple boxes like in OP's example, they are pushed down in your example: https://jsfiddle.net/j9nL1kjp/

Comment: yes because is relative . If you want to go upon you have to set the hidden div position:Absolute and the parent relative. But the question was about the hidden div .

Comment: sorry the parent div.box absolute

Answer (score 0):

No need for JavaScript, this can be done with just css:

```css
.parent {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s; /* Safari */
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
.parent:hover {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px
}

.child {
  visibility: hidden;
  }


.parent:hover .child {
  visibility: visible;
  }
```

```html
<div class="parent">Content
  <div class="child">More content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

[**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ux0u70j0/2/)

```css
.tile {
  width: 100px;
  background: lightgrey;
  float: left;
  margin: 6px;
  border: 3px solid green;
  transition: transform .2s ease-in;
}

.tile div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
}

.tile span {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: white;
}

.tile:hover {
  transform: scale(1.125);
}

.tile:hover span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tile">
  <div>Normal content</div>
  <span>New content</span>
</div>
<div class="tile">
  <div>Normal content</div>
  <span>New content</span>
</div>
<div class="tile">
  <div>Normal content</div>
  <span>New content</span>
</div>
```

Comment: When you have a smaller screen and the boxes are underneath eachother, they jump around on hover

Comment: @Pimskie This can be solved by having each tile inside of a container and just have the tile overflow freely.

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery and css we can achieve this

```
$(".img or div ").hover(function() {    
   $(this).closest(".img").css("z-index", 1);    
   $(this).animate({ height: "200", width: "200", left: "-=55", top: "-=55" }, "fast");    
}, function() {    
   $(this).closest(".img").css("z-index", 0);    
   $(this).animate({ height: "90", width: "90", left: "+=55", top: "+=55" }, "fast");    
});
```

if you need more information try searching for content like expanding div content on mouse hover.